# Functional JavaScript: What is the Hindley-Milner Type Signature of Compose?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, hindley-milner

Is the following attempt at the Hindley-Milner Type Signature for the compose function correct?

```
// compose :: (f -> [f]) -> (f -> f -> f) -> [f] -> f
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f,g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
```

Comment: How did you arrive at that type signature?

Comment: I think Hindley-Milner system only works with fixed arity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not correct. Your `compose` function takes an array of functions as input, and produces one (composed) function as the output, so that signature is clearly wrong. On the other hand, I don't think it's possible to write that function using the Hindley-Milner type system unless you make the assumption that all of the functions in `fns` are unary functions of the same type: `a -> a` (i.e. an array of [endomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism)).

```
compose :: [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
```

JavaScript is dynamically typed, so it actually allows each function in `fns` to be a different type (JS doesn't require arrays to be homogeneous). This means that you may need to ***invent some new syntax*** in order to express the type of `compose` as you have it. Here's how [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) (a functional utility library for JS) describes the type of [`R.compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose):

```
((y → z), (x → y), …, (o → p), ((a, b, …, n) → o)) → ((a, b, …, n) → z)
```

It uses this `…` syntax in order to represent a variadic function. The right-most function in the parameter list is of type `((a, b, …, n) → o)`, meaning that it is a variadic function that returns an `o`. This `o` is then used as the input of the next function which is of type `(o → p)`. This continues down the list of parameters until the left-most function is of type `(y → z)`, where `z` becomes the resultant type of calling the returned function: `((a, b, …, n) → z)`.

Comment: Great!!! I always wanted to decipher Ramda's compose notation

Answer (score 3):

The type of binary function composition is much easier to express in Hindley–Milner notation:

```
//    compose :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
const compose = f => g => x => f (g (x));
```